# How to fetch a SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue with odata/rest api/web - SharePoint Online

Tags: taxonomy, rest

I have a managed data field I would have to fetch using the url below
The field i would like to fetch is Divisions.
Is this possible?
Thanks in Advance

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=FirstName,Title,JobTitle,Birthday,Email,CellPhone,mBirthday,Divisions

<d:Divisions m:type="SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue">
 <d:Label>1</d:Label> 
   <d:TermGuid>78ed3264-8bab-4394-9612-582f920941de</d:TermGuid> 
    <d:WssId m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:WssId> 
</d:Divisions>
```

Updated code to fetch a TaxonomyFieldValue.I can see it in the console but when i loop through it doesn't work please see below

```
var requestUri = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View><Query></Query></View>'}";
// execute AJAX request
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,

    type: "POST",

    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
//This Works        
console.log(data.d.results[0].Divisions.Label);

        var newRows = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {



                newRows +="<li>";
                                //This doesntWorks 
                                newRows +="<p><span><strong>Division:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>" + data.d.results[i].Divisions.Label + " </span></p>";
                newRows +="<p><span><strong>Mobile Phone:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>" + data.d.results[i].CellPhone + "</span></p>";
                    newRows +="</li>";



}
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info? How are you making the REST request? Is it via JavaScript or C#? If so, then simply set the content-type to JSON, and retrieve the value (`Divisions.Label`).  Or is this via a workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen if your managed metadata column is a single-select ! [Here](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/taxonomy-columns-sharepoint-2013-list.html?showComment=1411555297896&_sm_au_=iFVS4N0LQ7sf9STj) is a great post that explains the caveat  and a workaround. You can use CAML query to retireve the values of the managed metadata.

**EDIT.**

Here is the code i got working now. I can get the managed metadata column values in the for loop. The "MMTest" is the name of my managed metadata column. Replace the site_url and list_name in the REST request URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function TestFunc()
{

$.ajax({
    url: "https://Site_url/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('List_Name')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View><Query></Query></View>'}",

    type: "POST",

    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) 
    {
              if(data.d.results[i].MMTest != null)
              {
                        alert(data.d.results[i].MMTest.Label);
              }
    }

    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error')
    }
});

}


</script>

<input type='button' id='btnCreateListitem' onClick='TestFunc()' value='Test'/>
```

Comment: Thanks vipul even when i use https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items
I still don't get the Label as a text but a number.This is a SharePoint Online site

Comment: Can't see the entire URL your comment. If i click the URL, looks like you have only used until /Items. Did you try using GetItems() as mentioned in the reference link from my post ?

Comment: Yes i used GetItems.I have updated my original post.Please see above.Thanks

Comment: So do you mean that you are now getting the value of the managed metadata ? You are having problems when generating the HTML ?

Comment: Yes when i trying looping through the managed metadata like the other fields
Vipul when i do this :data.d.results[i].Divisions.Label 
it doesnt work.See my original post.
when i do data.d.results[i].Divisions it returns null. Is my query right? All other fields work

Comment: Naijacoder, I have posted a working code in my edit. Also, I hope that all the items have a value in the managed metadata column. if not, you might want to check for NULL before you use the value. Probably that is the issue you might be facing.

Comment: Thanks Vipul looking at my original post im doing exactly what you are doing but getting error TypeError: data.d.results[i].Division is undefined.
Why?

Comment: as i said in my earlier comment, when you are looping through the items, are you checking for null values ? Or is it that all the items have a value in Divisions column ?I have posted an edit in my code to check for the condition. Take a look.

Comment: Cheers Vipul will give it a shot.

Comment: Glad it helped ! cheers

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it does not seem possible to retrieve `Label` from single-valued taxonomy field using SharePoint REST `GET` request.

The workaround is perform `POST` request to retrieve field values including taxonomy values as demonstrated below:

```
function postJson(endpointUrl,payload,success,failure)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      url: endpointUrl, 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}


function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryViewXml,success,failure)
{
   var queryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        } 
   }; 
   var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
   postJson(endpointUrl,queryPayload,success,failure);
}
```

**Usage**

It is assumed a `Contacts` list contains a single-valued taxonomy field named `Division`.

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Contacts','<View><Query/></View>',
  function(result){
      var items = result.d.results;
      //print info
      console.log('Found ' + items.length + ' contacts');   
      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if(items[i].Division)
             console.log(items[i].Division.Label);   
      }
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim i keep getting Divisions is null. How to check if taxanomy field is null? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is happening here? What does setting 'type' to 'SP.CamlQuery' do?